# Why is my custom UITableViewCell showing not displaying properly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with a single prototype cell in it. The cell has a label and a text field in it and has its class set to InputCell. When the table view loads the cell seems to be dequeued but displays as a default empty cell.

I have checked the following things:

- The Class of the TableViewController is set to my TableViewController subclass (ControlSettingsView)
- The TableViewController is the TableView's delegate and data source
- The custom cell has its class set to my TableViewCell sub class (InputCell)
- The custom cells reuse identifier is set to "input_cell" and this matches the identifier being used in my TableViewController.
- Make sure that the label and text field are in my cells content view not the cell itself.
- The constraints for the views in my cell look sensible.
- Set the cells background to red to make is stand out to check if the label and text field are not visible but the cell was being dequeued properly.

#### The function that navigates to my settings view from the root view controller

```
func gototSettingsFor(control: EditableUIElement) {
        let v = ControlSettingsView()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(v, animated: true)
    }
```

#### ControlSettingsView.swift

```
class ControlSettingsView: UITableViewController {

    let INPUT_CELL: String = "input_cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(InputCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: INPUT_CELL)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 5
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            let cell: InputCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: INPUT_CELL, for: indexPath) as! InputCell
            return cell
        default:
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: INPUT_CELL, for: indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

#### InputCell.swift

```
class InputCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cell_input: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cell_title: UILabel!

}
```

I would expect 5 of my custom table view cells to be displayed in the table view however i just get 5 empty cells, i can see the cells are there because if i tap on them they can be selected.

I can not fathom why it should be that the cell is not the custom cell but an empty one.

Comment: Did you try to debug the view hierarchy in Xcode, see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Comment: Assign default values to the label and text field. Are the cells still empty?  By the way, the `switch` in `cellForRow` is pointless if the same *identifier* is used. And the code crashes in section > 0 when you are going to assign values to the custom IBOutlets. And you have to **instantiate** the view controller. The default initializer `ControlSettingsView()` does not return the controller in the storyboard. Finally you must **not** register the cell if it's designed in the target table view in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the table view controller and prototype cell in the storyboard. But you are creating the view controller programmatically

```
let v = ControlSettingsView()
```

So the prototype cell properties will be nil. Create the view controller instance using storyboard identifier

Make sure you've set storyboard identifier `ControlSettingsView` for the view controller

```
if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ControlSettingsView") as? ControlSettingsView {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

And don't use [register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register) method if you have the tableview cell in the storyboard.

Comment: This fixed the problem thanks but i also had to remove the line ``` tableView.register(InputCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: INPUT_CELL)``` from my viewDidLoad. I did not know you had to load the views from the storyboard, thought it would be enough to instance the class as in my head they were linked.

Comment: @Chip yes. tableView.register should be used only if the table view cell is created programmatically without iboutlets

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not set any properties for the cell, nothing is displayed apart from an empty cell. Consider your following code:

```
let cell: InputCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: INPUT_CELL, for: indexPath) as! InputCell
return cell
```

**What you are doing now:** You are currently getting a dequeued cell, and returning it. However, you have not set any of the cell's properties.

**What you need to do:** You need to set some properties, like text or images, like so:

```
cell.textLabel = "MY TEXT HERE"
```

Or in your case you could do because of your custom `InputCell`:

```
cell.cell_title = "MY TEXT HERE"
```